# Python code to select/change photo region color & pattern

Tags: python

I am looking for some guidance on how to to write a piece of code (python preferred) to change the color/pattern of the counte top on this picture to something else the user will choose.I am looking into Python PIL right now but can't find a way to select/paste
new pattern into the picture. Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqLG6.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN6py.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Image` module to do what it is you are trying to accomplish.

```
import Image
picture = Image.open("/path/of/your/picture.jpg")

# Get the dimensions of your picture
width, height = picture.size()

# Process the pixels you are focused on
for x in width:
   for y in height:
       current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
       ####################################################################
       #create a new (R,G,B) tuple called new_color
       ####################################################################
       picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
```

Comment: I have a clear direction, thank you so much for your help! Do you know how to process the pixels for a non-rectangular shape? By going through height and width should work for rectangular but not for oddly shaped fills like the counter top picture.